# How EventHandler += method is implemented?

Tags: c#

I'm one day newbie in C#. Let's have

```cs
class C {
   // ...
   public event EventHandler Changed;
}
```

later we use it

```cs
cClassObject.Changed += new EventHandler(SomeOtherDelegate);
```

concepts are clear for me.

- delegate in langs like Scala would be FunctionN type, lambda.
- events are like object-level pub-sub Observable-like tool in C#.

**Question:**

Where and how operator **+=** is implemented?
I was unable to find its code, is it a special compiler thingy that is exclusive for that class?

Thanks

**Edit:**
[Here](http://csharpindepth.com/Resources.aspx) are some links by Jon Skeet for in-depth C# design (including Eric's suggested own blog).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it a special compiler thingy that is exclusive for that class?

It is a special compiler thingy. It's not bound to `EventHandler` though, but events in general. You can declare an event with any kind of delegate.

Behind the scenes, it just calls `Delegate.Combine` with a bit of synchronization to handle race conditions:

This code:

```
public event EventHandler Test;

public void Hello()
{
    Test += Program_Test
}
```

Will compile into:

```
private EventHandler Test;

public event EventHandler Test
{
  add
  {
    EventHandler eventHandler = this.Test;
    EventHandler comparand;
    do
    {
      comparand = eventHandler;
      eventHandler = Interlocked.CompareExchange<EventHandler>(ref this.Test, (EventHandler) Delegate.Combine((Delegate) comparand, (Delegate) value), comparand);
    }
    while (eventHandler != comparand);
  }
  remove
  {
    EventHandler eventHandler = this.Test;
    EventHandler comparand;
    do
    {
      comparand = eventHandler;
      eventHandler = Interlocked.CompareExchange<EventHandler>(ref this.Test, (EventHandler) Delegate.Remove((Delegate) comparand, (Delegate) value), comparand);
    }
    while (eventHandler != comparand);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi. do you mean all C# delegates possess Combine method? i.e. function composition is supported by C# by default?

Comment: Yes. `Delegate.Combine` is a static method that can be called on any kind of delegate. Behind the scenes, it returns a special kind of delegate: a MulticastDelegate (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Max: `Combine` is not composition in the traditional sense; normally we think of composition as a `Func<A, B>` composed with a `Func<B, C>` becomes a `Func<A, C>`.  `Combine` is simply *sequential* composition: the handlers are called one after the other.

Comment: Eric, Kevin, cheers, i'll be bombarding SO in nearest month looking for such internals :) . I'm coming from many languages so now its time for C# and its guts :D

Comment: @KevinGosse: Note that *all* delegates in C# are `MulticastDelegate`. The C# specification only *guarantees* that they derive from `Delegate`, but in fact every delegate type derives from `MulticastDelegate`.

Comment: @Max: I encourage you to obtain a paper copy of `The C# Programming Language` that has annotations from me and other C# experts; many of your questions will likely be answered therein.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for the info. I was under the illusion that `Delegate.Combine` returned an all-purpose MulticastDelegate, which required some bit of magic to be then recognized as `EventHandler` (or whatever delegate type). I now see that it's actually much simpler

Comment: @Max: Also consider reading my old MSDN blog, my new blog, and if how we changed event adder codegen in C# 4 particularly interests you, read Chris's blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cburrows/2010/03/04/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-i-locks/

Comment: cheers, colleagues. More blood and C# guts! :) I'll read that.